# Sorting functions not returning array correctly?

Tags: c++, arrays, bubble-sort, selection-sort

Just a simple homework assignment. This program will take the two listed arrays and sort them using the selection sort and bubble sort. It will keep track of the number of comparisons made for each sorting technique and then display those values at the end of the program. The program should also display both of the sorted arrays, however, in this instance the arrays are not being outputted correctly. I'm assuming the issue lies in with either of the sorting functions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 20;

void bubbleSort(int[], int&);
void selectionSort(int[], int&);
void displayResults(int[], int[], int, int);

int main()
{
    int list1[SIZE] = { 6, 9, 56, 78, 45, 64, 80, 4, 67, 89, 38, 61, 40,
        71, 54, 92, 19, 69, 30, 99 };

    int list2[SIZE] = { 6, 9, 56, 78, 45, 64, 80, 4, 67, 89, 38, 61, 40,
        71, 54, 92, 19, 69, 30, 99 };

    int exchange1 = 0;
    int exchange2 = 0;

    bubbleSort(list1, exchange1);

    selectionSort(list2, exchange2);

    displayResults(list1, list2, exchange1, exchange2);
}

void displayResults(int array1[], int array2[], int exchange1, int
                                                                   exchange2)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of exchanges made by each sort algorithm:\n";
    cout << "************************************************" << endl;
    cout << "List 1: " << array1[SIZE] << endl;
    cout << "List 2: " << array2[SIZE] << endl;
    cout << "************************************************" << endl;
    cout << setw(42) << left << "Bubble sort:" << right << exchange1 << endl;
    cout << setw(42) << left << "Selection sort:" << right << exchange2
         << endl;
    cout << "************************************************" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

void bubbleSort(int array[], int& exchange)
{
    int temp;
    bool swap;

    do {
        swap = false;
        for (int count = 0; count < (SIZE - 1); count++) {
            if (array[count] > array[count + 1]) {
                temp = array[count];
                array[count] = array[count + 1];
                array[count + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
                exchange++;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);
}

void selectionSort(int array[], int& exchange2)
{
    int startScan = 0;
    int minIndex;
    int minValue;

    for (int startScan = 0; startScan < (SIZE - 1); startScan++) {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = array[startScan];
        for (int i = startScan + 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
            if (array[i] < minValue) {
                minValue = array[i];
                minIndex = i;
                exchange2++;
            }
        }
        array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
        array[startScan] = minValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: ***I'm assuming the issue lies in with either of the sorting functions?*** Anytime you get into this situation you need to use your debugger to step through your code 1 line at a time looking at the flow of the execution and the values of the variables at each step.

Comment: `cout << "List 1: " << array1[SIZE] << endl;` is undefined behavior and the wrong way to print a statically sized array. You are actually attempting to print a single value at that is one position past the end of the array. To print you probably want a loop of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not displaying the arrays because you haven't implemented anything in your code to display the array ,

```
void displayResults(int array1[], int array2[], int exchange1, int exchange2)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of exchanges made by each sort algorithm:\n";
    cout << "************************************************" << endl;
    cout << "List 1: " << array1[SIZE] << endl;
    cout << "List 2: " << array2[SIZE] << endl;
    cout << "************************************************" << endl;
    cout << setw(42) << left << "Bubble sort:" << right << exchange1 << endl;
    cout << setw(42) << left << "Selection sort:" << right << exchange2
         << endl;
    cout << "************************************************" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Here `array1[SIZE]` and `array2[SIZE]` , don't display the array , they access an out of bound value from the array(max index for arrays is 19) , thus their behaviour is undefined . 
Now to actually display the array , you will need to write proper code to display the array as

```
void display(int *arr , int size)
{
    for(unsigned i=0;i<size;++i)
        cout<<*(arr+i)<<ends;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Why `ends`? That's a very obscure manipulator which doesn't serve any purpose here. And why `*(arr+i)` instead of `arr[i]` which is surely more familar to the OP.

Comment: I used `ends` to give space after each element so that they are separated as well as to flush the buffer at the same time . This manipulator seems the best way to do this task .  
And about `*(arr+i)` , that just makes things more clear to me , as if the array be having more than 1 dimension , then simply using `arr[i][j][...]` won't always be an option . Did you just downvote my answer due to these issues ?

Comment: `ends` adds a nul character (`'\0'`) not a space, it doesn't flush the stream either. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ends. I cancelled my upvote, I haven't down voted as your answer is basically correct.

Comment: Sorry my bad , i guess printing of null character gave me appearance of a space and about flushing the buffer , i thought i read about this in C++ primer , though on checking through the internet , i was clearly wrong . But if you cancelled your upvote , then my question should have '-1' votes , and sorry for blaming you for the downvote

Answer (score 0):

You used arrays correctly many times in your sorting functions. `array[count] = array[count + 1];` for instance to assign one array element to another.

Then suddenly in your display function you seem to think that `array1[SIZE]` is going to display the whole array.

If you want to display an array you should do it with a loop and an index, exactly as you did in your sorting functions

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    cout << array1[i] << ' ';
cout << endl;
```